# Join two sql queries ,two original queries as temporary tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have two SQL (Oracle) queries.

Query #1:

```
select 
    nomhotel, max(nombre) as mxnb 
from 
    (select nomhotel, typechambre, count(typechambre) as nombre         
     from 
         (select h.nomhotel, c2.typechambre 
          from hotel h, reservation r, chambre c2 
          where h.ville = 'Alger' 
            and h.numhotel = c2.numhotel 
            and c2.numhotel = r.numhotel 
            and c2.numchambre = r.numchambre) 
     group by 
         nomhotel, typechambre) 
group by 
    nomhotel
```

Query #2:

```
select 
    nomhotel, typechambre, count(typechambre) as nombre 
from 
    (select 
         h.nomhotel, c2.typechambre 
     from
         hotel h, reservation r, chambre c2 
     where
         h.ville = 'Alger' 
         and h.numhotel = c2.numhotel 
         and c2.numhotel = r.numhotel 
         and c2.numchambre = r.numchambre) 
group by 
    nomhotel, typechambre
```

Where

- query1.nomhotel = query2.nomhotel, and
- query1.mxnb = query2.count(typechambre)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: You haven’t actually asked a question. What is the question, what have you tried and what specific issue you are facing?

Comment: Ask A question!!!!... Please!!!

Answer (score 0):

If your queries are working ok then all you have to do is just join them on conditions that are also stated at the end of your question. Something like here:

```sql
Select
   q1.columns, q2.columns, .....
From
   (your Query1 in brackets) q1
Inner Join
   (your Query2 in brackets) q2 ON(q2.nomhotel = q1.nomhotel And q2.nombre = q1.mxnb)
```

Or using Common Table Expressions (CTEs) like here:

```sql
WITH 
  q1 AS 
    (your query1),
  q2 AS
    (your query2)
Select
   q1.columns, q2.columns, .....
From
    q1
Inner Join
    q2 ON(q2.nomhotel = q1.nomhotel And q2.nombre = q1.mxnb)
```

Regards...